# Security group for AWS Lambda to access RDS

Tags: amazon-rds, aws-lambda

Was not able to find any security groups for AWS Lambda.

Is there a way to allow access from AWS Lambda to RDS without alowing all IPs (0.0.0.0/0) and without allowing all Amazon IP Range?

Answer (score 5):

As @user5919440 suggests, now that this new feature is out:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-access-resources-in-a-vpc-from-your-lambda-functions/

...you simply need to tell AWS Lambda which VPC subnets to bind to your function. The function then can communicate with any AWS service that also has access to that subnet.

This means that you should be able to add a security group in your RDS that allows traffic from the same *internal* subnet (10.x.x.x) that your Lambda function is bound to.

Comment: Currently, if you go to "edit inbound rules" in the RDS security group there is a "source" column and if you click on the search button you can select VPCs from the drop down menu.

Answer (score 4):

This feature is out as of yesterday

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-access-resources-in-a-vpc-from-your-lambda-functions/

Comment: but what if i have no VPC? I have API Gateway + Lambda + RDS. Also I have EC2, but this is not related to the problem

Answer (score 0):

There currently isn't, and a moment's reflection suggests that if there were, if would be a false sense of security -- the traffic wouldn't be assured to be from *your* Lambda functions... but from *anybody's* -- the IP addresses are pooled.

There have been hints of a future mechanism to allow a cleaner trust relationship between Lambda and VPC, perhaps implemented with the [VPC Endpoint](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-endpoints.html) feature (currently available only with S3), or perhaps differently... no details have been forthcoming, so far.